# jQuery não soma "+"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, matemática

Estou fazendo um carrinho de compras com `jQuery`. O carrinho funciona assim: Tem os produtos e todos os valores de cada um. Tem um campo que altera a quantidade. Tem outro campo também do frete. Após somar todos os produtos ele da um subtotal de por exemplo, **R$ 50,00**. Quando a pessoa calcula o frete, da por exemplo **R$ 20,00**. Então o subtotal é **R$ 50,00** (produtos) e mais **R$ 20.00** do frete. Tem um box que fica a soma dos dois, no caso **R$ 70,00**. Quando altera a quantidade de produtos o valor do `box` tem que diminuir ou aumentar (depende se o usuário está adicionando +1 ou -1). O problema é:

Quando o usuário altera a quantidade, para por exemplo **2** o subtotal fica certo, por exemplo **R$ 60,00**, só que o box envez de somar **R$ 60,00** + Frete ele só joga o Subtotal no box e esquece de somar o frete. O meu código jQuery é:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("input#quantidade_carrinho").change(function(){

                var id_produto = $(this).attr('data-ref');
                var baseURL = $("#baseURL").val();
                var quantidade = $(this).val();

                var preco = $("#data-"+id_produto).val();
                var valor_total = parseFloat((preco * quantidade).toFixed(2));

                $("#total-"+id_produto).html('R$ '+parseFloat(valor_total).toFixed(2));

                $.ajax({

                    url: baseURL+'ajax/atualiza_carrinho',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id:id_produto, quantidade:quantidade},

                    success:function(callbackAjax){

                        var callback = $.trim(callbackAjax);

                         var frete = $("#fretehidden").val(); //Pega o valor do Frete em um campo Hidden

                        var subtotal = parseFloat(callback).toFixed(2); //Pega o subtotal que está em um hidden (está funcionando)
                        var subtotalcomfrete = parseFloat(subtotal+frete).toFixed(2); //Aqui ele deveria somar o subtotal + frete só que não soma, só fica o subtotal

                        $(".subtotal-ajax").html('R$ '+ subtotal); //Funciona
                        $("#subtotal").val(subtotal); //Funciona

                        alert('Subtotal:' + subtotal+' - Subtotal com Frete '+subtotalcomfrete+' - Frete: '+frete); //Exibe por exemplo R$ 50,00 - R$ 50,00 - R$ 20,00... O que deveria aparecer é R$ 50,00 - R$ 70,00 - R$ 20,00

                        $('span.preco-total').html('R$ '+subtotalcomfrete);
                        $('span.valor_parcela').html(parseFloat(subtotalcomfrete/3).toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

Comment: Se você mudar a linha `var frete = $("#fretehidden").val();` para `var frete = parseFloat($("#fretehidden").val());`, o que acontece?

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda:
http://jsfiddle.net/k5hdxs2c/

Comment: @KaduAmaral mesma coisa.

Comment: (parseFloat('5')+parseFloat('7')).toFixed(2), e assim?

Comment: Eu tirei os .toFixed(2) e parseFloat() e só coloquei eles em algumas variaveis e deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Alisson, elabore uma resposta mostrando o que tu fez que deu certo. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao fazer:

```
var subtotalcomfrete = parseFloat(subtotal+frete).toFixed(2);
```

Você está concatenando um numero com uma string. O correto seria:

```
var subtotalcomfrete = subtotal + parseFloat(frete).toFixed(2);
```

Além do mais tome cuidado com "." e "," nos campos input. Você sempre deve usar "." para separar os decimais